# OpenStaxk: use cpu accross multi servers

Tags: cpu, openstack

I have Blade Server and I want to know that how its possible to use cpu/ram between blades.

I want to have a machine with 32 physical cpu and I want all cpus work together.

Is it possible to share cpu between servers ?

Comment: What is your software you want to run on 32 cpus?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible without explicit support from the software. You can't run single-thread program on several cpu cores; and you can ru multi thread program on different unconnected (not coherent) physical cpus.

Different blades are different servers, every one of them has own OS instance. They have no memory coherence, only network connection, so it is task of your software (and of its programmer) to split the task between several processes and connect them using network. In computer clusters there is MPI interface to make programming of such programs easier.

There were several project to *emulate* shared memory system (or single OS instance system) using cluster of PCs without coherent memory, but they are abandoned and/or too slow: Intel cluster openmp, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_system_image (MOSIX/OpenMOSIX), ScaleMP, different software DSM (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_shared_memory#Software_DSM_implementation)...